# How to update to latest snapshots in Hudson

Tags: java, maven, hudson

I have a project with ~20 Maven libraries. Until recently we've been developing only SNAPSHOTS. However, now we are starting to work towards producing releases. We use Hudson for our continuous integration and have all the trunk versions of our project as jobs. I am using the Maven release plugin to release the projects.

Since the Maven release plugin advances the version of the trunk file, how do you typically keep all the Hudson jobs pointing to the latest SNAPSHOTS?

Answer (score 0):

It should be pointing to the project directory and thus pick it up automatically. In other words, it looks at the pom.xml and gets its information from that. So, after the release, you'll be on the new snapshot, and the next Hudson build will be too. Hudson will never build the release or the old one after the pom is changed.

Do you have some kind of setup where the project directory/name includes the actual version? That would seem pretty strange.

Comment: Sorry I meant how do other projects in Hudson point to the new SNAPSHOT version of a library. Is this a manual process or can it be automated i.e. so your Hudson jobs are always being built against the trunk version irrespective of its Maven SNAPSHOT version.

Comment: I guess I'm confused. I don't see how it wouldn't be building against the trunk version always if that's where your job is pointed at. Or do you want other projects to point to the new snapshot without changing the pom? Do you want the pom dependencies to somehow update to the new versions?

Comment: Yes. If I have 2 projects A and B, where project A 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT depends on project B 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT. If B is updated to 0.2.0-SNAPSHOT from 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT then project A (I assume) will continue to depend on project B 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT. At this point project A is no longer being continuously integrated with project B. Presumably I need to update the project A pom - which with a large number of projects would become a fairly sizeable maintenance overhead.

Comment: Well, it wouldn't point to the old snapshot, it'd point to the release, since you can't release something with a snapshot dependency. As far as I know, what you want to do is not possible (someone else might chime in here).

Comment: Incidentally, if you're keeping most/everything on the same version, this is a good reason to use a version property in a parent pom or something similar, then you'd have one or only a few places to update the version.